# SharePoint Survey Heading- How do I delete the (New Item) that shows after the heading

Tags: 2010, survey

When I click on Respond to this Survey, another window opens up with the questions of the survey. The header is what is giving me a problem.

I was able to go into `Settings` -> `Survey Settings` -> `Title, description and Navigation` and change the Name of the Survey, but when the Respond to Survey link is clicked it shows the name of the Survey that I put in and it also shows `New Item` in front of the survey name.

How do I delete `New Item`.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this when adding link sets to pages too. Try this to see if it works.
First make sure that the response page is not showing up in a popup. If so then go into the settings and change that. You can change it back after.
1. Click on Respond to survey
2. Click Edit page
3. Click edit web part in the survey block
4. In the options go down to Miscellaneous and Uncheck "Show Toolbar with Ribbon"
That should do it.
Images:
[image]

[image]